# Add stripes or patterns shape in a bar graph figure

Tags: matlab

I am trying to add a pattern or a stripes as shown in the photo but I could find it in the properties .. Do anyone know which property should I change to add that pattern shape ??

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try this submission to FEX: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24021-hatch-fill-patterns-plus-color---invert.  Here's a sample of what the file can generate: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/screenshots/5536/original.jpg .  Here's a MATLAB Central discussion that talks about how to use the above library to achieve textured bar graphs: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98563-how-do-i-show-striped-patterns-or-any-other-texture-for-specific-bars-when-using-the-bar-function-al

Comment: @rayryeng You should definitely post that as an answer with a couple of images! Its too useful to be left as a comment!

Comment: thanks @rayryeng ... but this force me to write the code and draw the graph again.. but my problem is that I need to change it from the properties without rewriting the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
    x = [ 0.1 1 5 10 12 15 ];
    y = [1.9278   20.0206   73.7318   80.8813   81.4757   85.4117];
    figure;
    bar(x,y);
    colormap(cool(8));
    im_hatch = applyhatch_pluscolor(gcf,'\|-.+/',0,[1 1 0 1 0 0],[],200,3,2);
    imwrite(im_hatch,'test.png','png')
```

Comment: Is that possible to do by Octave?